# cannot access gmail account and suspect hacking

Tags: google-account, account-recovery

I have a gmail account which I last accessed in March 2012. Today I received a notification from Google that the password had recently been modified. I tried to access the account in order to reset the password as I was not at the origine of the change.

First, it is impossible for me to click on the option for the recovery email, the system only allows that i click on the option "i no longer have access to these"

Second, I do not recognise the first and last letter of the recovery email (which leads me to believe the account has been hacked)

Unfortunately, even though I followed the steps and tried to answer the questions as best as I could I keep getting told that the answers were not consistent with the account and o try again.

What can I do? Can I ask Google/gmail to close down the account if I cannot have access to it? I would really hate for someone to use my account for fraudulent purposes.

Comment: [Contact *Gmail*](https://support.google.com/mail/?hl=en)

Comment: While I understand where you're coming from, I'd be really concerned if you can convince Google to shut down an account you can't prove is yours.

Comment: Do you have a secondary email or phone? If not, now is the time to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to report the issue to Google as soon as possible. I advised a colleague in the past to follow these instructions [on Google support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/134413) and he managed to regain access to his account.

Comment: Those instructions are for G Suite.